# Show all hidden table rows when selecting empty option in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far my code works fine but when I select `empty select option`, all the rows in my table should be visible (in other words reset the table to initial state) again. How do I do it?

I've seen this ([JQuery Selector for table with hidden row - alternate row colouring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853063/jquery-selector-for-table-with-hidden-row-alternate-row-colouring)) but couldn't apply to my structure.

Thanks

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#cars").change(function()
        {
            var selected = $(this).val();

            if (selected != '')
            {
                var values = $.map($('#cars>option'), function(e) { return e.value; });

                values.forEach(function(item)
                {
                    if (item != '')
                    {
                        if (selected == item)
                        {
                            $('.' + item).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('.' + item).hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Show all rows
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
            <tr id="header">
                <td>1</td>
                <td><select id="cars">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                    <option value="audi">AUDI</option>
                    <option value="mercedes">MERCEDES</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bmw">
                <td>3.16</td>
                <td>BMW</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bmw">
                <td>3.18</td>
                <td>BMW</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bmw">
                <td>3.00</td>
                <td>BMW</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="audi">
                <td>A1</td>
                <td>AUDI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="audi">
                <td>A3</td>
                <td>AUDI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mercedes">
                <td>300sel</td>
                <td>MERCEDES</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`Working Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/4kWZs/)***
Add this *else* part in your code

```
else {
    $('table tr').show();
}
```

Comment: I assigned an `id` to the table and doing this now: `$('#table1 tr').show();`

Answer (score 0):

just place this:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr:hidden').show();
```

---

Although you can simplify your code like this:

```
$("#cars").change(function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();
   this.value !== '' ? $('.'+this.value).show() : $(this).closest('table').find('tr:hidden').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily complex.  You don't need `map`, `foreach`, etc.

```
$("#cars").change(function()
 {
   $('tr[id!=header]').hide()
   if (this.value)
     $('.' + this.value).show()
   else
     $('tr').show()
  }
)
```